# In SSRS How to Set Dynamic Body Height/Width?

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssrs-2014

In SSRS How to Set Dynamic Body Height/Width based on data coming.

I am looking for Report Properties Height and Width property because when I export to PDF I need to be get output in a single page.

for Example today I am having 10 records and report is exporting well in PDF but gradually data increases to 50 records and when I export report in PDF it is not coming in single page instead it is coming in 2 Pages, so let me know how to accommodate all the records in a single page when I am exporting to PDF?

Report Properties --> height/width in inches or centimeter.

Comment: You aren't really asking a specific question.  Please check out [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [provide more details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you solve your issue.

Comment: What are you expecting SSRS to do when there is more data than can be displayed on one page?  Are you looking for a way to scale down the font?  Other than than that, there really isn't much you can do to fit more data on one page (assuming that you have your rows set to be as compact as possible with a minimum row height and Top and Bottom padding set to "0").

Comment: Yes I am expecting SSRS to do when there is more/less data than can be displayed on one page.